# How do you get 3 stars on Pig Bang 1-13 in Angry Birds Space?

Tags: angry-birds-space

I've succeeded in taking out all three pigs with my first (of three) birds.    That earns me a paltry one star.

What's the trick?

Comment: What score did you get killing 3 birds?

Comment: I'm embarassed to admit that I'd meant another board.    Since this is still a legit question, with a correct, clear answer, I've accepted it and I'll ask a new one, rather than edit this one.

Comment: Sorry about that, but thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can hit the 3rd vertical board at the top at the right spot (screenshot below), it will cause enough force to cause the cement block to drop on the first pig, and the ice block to hit the 2nd pig, which will then push things enough to knock over the tower with the 3rd pig.

I did this 3 times and averaged about 48,000 on each attempt which was enough for 3 stars on the iOS version.

[image: Die Piggy]