# How do you get 3 stars on Pig Bang 1-14 in Angry Birds Space?

Tags: angry-birds-space

I've succeeded in taking out all three pigs with my first (of three) birds. That earns me a paltry one star.

What's the trick?

**NOTE**:  I previously asked a [very similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/57687/16) for another board.   I'm not cylcling through them one by one.    That was intended to be about THIS board 1-14, but since someone legitimately answered it as asked, I thought it fairer to ask another question, rather than edit that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This level is pretty tricky. To earn three stars, you need approximately 75k points. Therefore, completing it with three stars, as you can see, means using all three birds to cause maximum damage instead of completing it with only one bird. Here are a few basic facts to keep in mind when playing this level:

- The birds you're throwing only has a small explosive radius, where blocks are destroyed. Blocks outside this radius are thrown off but not damaged (until they hit another block)
- Blocks that fly outside the playing area do not count as destroyed, and therefore do not increase your score
- This level takes place in space, with no gravity and surrounding planets for blocks to smash against (except for the rock which you're slinging birds from)

Here's a strategy I've found that works pretty regularly:

1. Hit the topmost wood cluster. Try to angle it such that the bird clips on the top of the stone cluster slightly.

   [image]

   If necessary, manually trigger the explosion when the bird is closest to the center of the cluster. This will send wood blocks flying into position of the three pigs, and it's likely you'll kill at least two of them.
2. Send the second bird towards the top of the bottom front cluster of stones. This will clear the center of the stones, allowing the third bird to fly in unhindered.

   [image]
3. Send the third bird straight ahead, or towards wherever the remaining wood block of the center back cluster is densest. The last two birds may have to be thrown in rapid succession if the first bird knocks out all three pigs.

   [image]

   Success! As always, you may have to try a few times, if for instance the last pig won't die for some reason or your second bird fails to clear the center area for the last bird.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Definitely one of the trickier levels I've found.