# Can you complete all Angry Birds Space levels using only one bird?

Tags: angry-birds-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you get three stars on all Angry Birds Space levels using only one bird?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73373/can-you-get-three-stars-on-all-angry-birds-space-levels-using-only-one-bird)

I have completed all of the levels in Pig Bang and some in the next world using only one bird. Can I complete the whole game using only one bird per level?

Comment: Exact duplicate from the same person.

Comment: I would not say that it's strictly an exact duplicate (completion != 3-star scoring), but yeah, close enough IMO.

Comment: @all I meant to ask this te first time, but I accidentally said three stars and already had an answer that was true to the accidental question, and it was too late to change, so I asked a new one instead of having a rollback cuz those suck