# What is the meaning of this turnip?

Tags: angry-birds-space

It looks suspicious.

[image: Or maybe a parsnip?]

Is there any reason I should go after it? I can't reach it with the red cadet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The turnips can be destroyed for 1000 points. They aren't evil or special. You'll find some others littered across other levels, but they don't provide any special functionality currently. You do want to keep an eye out for golden eggs though.

In the level above (Pig Bang 13), you can destory this one with the blue bird, but I'm pretty sure to 3 star the level, you should be [finishing the level with the first bird](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57687/how-do-you-get-3-stars-on-pig-bang-1-13-in-angry-birds-space).

Answer (score 1):

It looks indeed suspicious, but at the moment there is no special reason to hit it other then few points. If you want to try by yourself you can reach it using the blue bird.

Answer (score 1):

There are many objects for bonus points in Angry Birds that you might look out for in Pig Bang, including:

1. Space turnips. They can be acheived by touching them, allowing you to get 1000 points.
2. Purple Mushrooms: They can be achieved by touching them too, allowing you to get 3000  points. This would be hard to achieve as it spawns in a pretty hard place for you to achieve. i.e : inside a building or covered by walls.
3. Golden Eggs. You cannot earn any points in the level, by once you touch it, a wormhole will appear and you will directly be transferred from into different reprises of arcade games, such as space invaders, bubble shooter and more.

   Now, returning to your question. You can reach it with the blue birds, but I wouldn't recommend it. This turnip only costs 1000 points, which is very little compared to what you earn when destroying the pigs(5000 points). Therefore, you shouldn't try to get the turnip, but to attack the pigs. But if you want to get the highest score available, then you'll have to do so.